# NSIS license page

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

Is there anyway you could resize the rich textbox in the license page of an NSIS installer?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- there are several choices that affect the size a little bit, checkbox vs button etc
- Switch to the Modern UI if you are not already using it
- Copy and resize one of the dialogs in \Contrib\UIs with resource hacker and use ChangeUI in your script
- Call GetWindowRect/ScreenToClient/SetWindowPos with the system plugin at runtime in the show callback function for the page